# How to get subreddits of current user?

Tags: c#, reddit

I trying to write simple application that will notify me about new posts in my subreddits from few hours ago.

example of code is:

```
var reddit = new RedditClient("this is appId", "this is refreshToken");
string subRedditor = "funny";
Subreddit sr = reddit.Subreddit(subRedditor).About();
DateTime dtAfter = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-8);
List<Post> searchedPosts = sr.Posts.GetNew(new CategorizedSrListingInput(after: dtAfter.ToString(), limit: 100));
for (int i=0; i<searchedPosts.Count; i++)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(searchedPosts[i].Created+" | "+ searchedPosts[i].Title+" | "+searchedPosts[i].Listing.URL);
   }
```

It works nice when I know subreddit name. But the names are nonconstant values, they can change if moderators want. So I wonder to know Is exists some api to get subreddits of current user?
Something like this:

```
User currUser = reddit.User(); 
currUser.GetSubreddits;
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what SDK you use, so I've assumed it's Reddit.NET by Kris Craig.

Subscribed subreddits can be accessed via the MySubscribedSubreddits method in the Account class:

`var subscribed = reddit.Account.MySubscribedSubreddits();`

Comment: Thank you! I forgot SDK, sorry. You right. This works.